# postgres: can I declare functional dependencies?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If, for a given table, the value of a column `c` is determined by the values of columns `(a, b)`, is there a way to declare this fact to postgres??

I'm asking because the examples given for `group by` mention that, if you group by the primary key, you can use any other column of the table in the select-list, because it will be functionally dependent on the primary key. However, I have not been able to find anything in the documentation that extends this to other columns or column combinations.

Comment: You should read the basics of relational model, especially about [2NF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) and 3NF. DBMS just manages your data, it does not know anything about it's relationship (except PK/FK constraint). So it is the question to you about your model.

Comment: @astentx: yes, that's why I'm asking if I can *declare* that a dependency exists. Further  normalization is not always practical.

Comment: @blue_note I am afraid astentx doesn't really understand your question. Unfortunately, the engine is aware of the functional dependency, but you still have to use *dummy* aggregates , like `SUM(c)` or `MAX(c)` to silence it.

Comment: @wildplasser I understand the question, but `MAX(c)` is the way you manage this dependency, not DBMS. Because you know it exists and you can guarantee the correct result. Also group by PK guarantees access to other columns because your table is that functional dependency. So, the only way is to normalize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, feature that you want is not supported now (2020).